# Marked slides using Beamer for learning?

Tags: beamer

How to mark slides of beamer, with a blue circle on them?
I was a blue circle on some slides, to indicate that it is important slide.

The mark should be on top-right corner preferably. Thank you so much !

I was thinking to use footnote, and to say that on those marks there is not footnote numbering.
However I should keep footnote to work, because on some slides, I give the references for the figures, considering the ref. author,... journal..

I am looking forward to hearing you, and I would like to kindly thank you for your help and valuable information. 
Best regards

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{title in head/foot}\usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Section 1}
\begin{itemize}
\item line1
\begin{itemize}
\item item1
\item item2
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}



\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Section}
this a text
    abc\footnote{text}
\begin{itemize}
\item line1
\end{itemize}
\end{frame} 


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Section}
this a text
\begin{itemize}
\item line1
    abcdef\footnote{text}
\item line2
    abcdef\footnote{text}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame} 



\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Section}
this a text

    abc\footnote{text}

\begin{itemize}
\item line1
\end{itemize}
\end{frame} 



\end{document}
```

Comment: Would you mind to add a sketch of the desired output to your question? Currently I don't understand where you want your blue circle to appear.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be exactly what you have in mind, but I define a command like `\newcommand{\markslide}{\textcolor{blue}{\textbullet~}}`, which I add to the `frametitle` of slides I want to emphasize, like `\frametitle{\markslide An important slide}`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newcommand{\markslide}{\textcolor{blue}{\textbullet~}}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Some slide}
\begin{itemize}
\item line1
\begin{itemize}
\item item1
\item item2
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\markslide An important slide}
this a text
    abc
\begin{itemize}
\item line1
\end{itemize}
\end{frame} 


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Some other slide}
this a text
\begin{itemize}
\item line1
    abcdef
\item line2
    ghijkl
\end{itemize}
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi would it be possible to leave in free, the frametitle because I use it already.

Comment: Is it possible that the BLUE Sticker or Blue Mark comes on the top right hand corner, like on a top layer (without touching to frame title) ?    This help would be fabulous if you can help me !! Thanks a lot in advance !!! Can the mark slide be also a bit bigger on the top right side (no text needed, just a sticker, the student knows that an important slide).